# jquery wont click on new generated class, tried delegate

Tags: jquery, css

I have a button, when I click it I add the class `revert-back`, when I then click this new class nothing happens. I originally tried a simple `.click` on its own, but as that wasnt working I found some answers that talked of using `.delegate`. The problem is when I use this, it clicks immediately and automatically

So what happens is as soon as I click `show-more` it instantly slides up again and shows the 'Button Clicked' Alert.

```
$(".show-more").click(function () {
    $(".show-more-products").addClass("revert-back");
    $(".show-more-products").removeClass("show-more");
    $(".all-products").slideDown(100);
    $('.show-more-products').html('Show Less');
});
$('.product-grid').delegate('.revert-back', 'click', function () {
    alert('Button Clicked');
    $(".all-products").slideUp(100);
});
```

Comment: Some html and css would help. Even better would be s fiddle.

Comment: It's not relevant to your question, but you should also recognize how intensive the CSS based querying is and cache those. `var showMoreLinks = $('.show-more-products');` and then perform your addClass, removeClass, etc. on the the variable.

Comment: .live should have done it, but is deprecated. So use .on. If that still gives your trouble, use a plugin called livequery.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.on()` instead.

```
$('.product-grid').on('click','.revert-back', function () {
     alert ('Button Clicked');
     $(".all-products").slideUp(100);
});
```

Comment: unfortunately nothing happens at all when I use that, but thanks anyway.